# matplotlib change boxplot mean/median according to hue colormap group

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, boxplot

I am having some issues setting the mean or median color respectively of the hue group for matplotlib and seaborn.

For testing sake I generate here some basic data

```
import seaborn as sn 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

arr_num = np.random.randint(0, 4, (3, 1000))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr_num.T)
df["cat"] = np.random.choice(a=['a', 'b'],  size=1000)
df.columns = ["num_1", "num_2", "num_3", "cat_1"]
df.head()
```

Then I am calling the seaborn boxplot function:

```
ax = sn.boxplot(data=df, x="num_1", y="num_2", hue="cat_1", palette="viridis", \
          medianprops={"color":"blue"})
```

[image]

Here the medianpropos parameter is actually a [matplotlib.lines.Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html), which allows only the color argument. In the upper example I set this to blue, but I am not seeing an option to specify here different colors for the two "hue" groups.

Theoretically I could generate the two colors with the [seaborn.color_palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html) function, e.g. `sn.color_palette("viridis", 2)`. But still I don't see any way to specify those for the individual groups.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This type of functionality isn't currently supported.  An approach could be to iterate through the generated artists and color them afterwards.  But this is quite cumbersome as it isn't straightforward to find out which artist coincides with which statistic.  Matplotlib's boxplot has more options to change things after creation, but with matplotlib there is no concept of hue via category, and grouping is much more manual.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC for the quick reply. When I am going through the ax.lines list of matplotlib.lines.Line2D objects, I can actually set the color using the function ax.lines[0].set_color("red"). But how do I know that the given line is actually a median line? 
Otherwise I could think of a "hack", that I previously set the median alpha in the medianprops to a specific value and then check in an itereation if the alpha is set to this value, and if so change the color accordingly. But indeed it seems like a quite messy solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion with @JohanC, there does not seem to be a simple method.
So I am posting here my "hacky" solution that fixes the median props to a certain alpha value and then itereates through it setting the colormap specific values. For better code visibility I set the boxes to lower alpha values.

```
ax = sn.boxplot(data=df, x="num_1", y="num_2", hue="cat_1", palette="viridis", \
          medianprops={"alpha":0.0124})

hue_colors = sn.color_palette("viridis", df["cat_1"].unique().shape[0])

for patch in ax.artists:
    r, g, b, a = patch.get_facecolor()
    patch.set_facecolor((r, g, b, .1))

switch_ = 0
for line in ax.lines:
    if line.get_alpha() == 0.0124:
        
        line.set_color(hue_colors[switch_])
        switch_ += 1
        
        if switch_ >= len(hue_colors):
            switch_ = 0
            
        line.set_alpha(1)
```

[image]

EDIT: For changing the mean color instead of the median, the `set_color` function won't work. Instead set the edgecolor and facecolor independently:

```
line._markerfacecolor = hue_colors[switch_]
line._markeredgecolor = hue_colors[switch_]
```